# How to get a list of all "shortcut widget" apps?

Tags: android, android-widget

In drawer there are some widgets that work like shortcuts to some predefined actions for example: Direct Dial, Quick message, Directions & Navigation, etc. I would like to get list of all such widgets installed on my device. `AppWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders()` function does not return this type of widgets. I tried also `PackageManager.getInstalledApplications()` and even `PackageManager.getInstalledPackages(int flags)` but with no success.

EDIT:
I found the solution. I had to use `PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent intent, int flags)` with intent set to `Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT`.

Comment: Have you been able to figure out how to launch it once you have the resolve info?